# How to run a query when a button is pressed and export results to Excel File

Tags: ms-access

I have a form which has a combobox and a button. When a value is selected in it, I have to retrieve the value selected in combo box and based on that value run a query. The query produces a table of 5 columns. I want this table to be exported to Excel Sheet. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

As Tom said, you can use the Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet command. First you need to have your query set to be a parameterized query that references your combobox. I'm assuming it's part of your WHERE clause. So, your query may look like:

```
 SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE values = [Forms]![yourForm]![yourComboBox];
```

Assuming your query you just wrote is named "qryExport", You'll put this code into a button on your form on the on click event:

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "qryExport", "C:\yourPath\exportedReport.xlsm", True
```

You should then be able to go in the path you specified and open that excel file and make sure everything worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Where should this query be written by changing it in the way you said. I was doing it by having a query in string and feeding it to OpenRecordSet in VBA. Please help.

Comment: Just create a query, go to SQL view, and type that query in. Save the query as whatever name you reference on your form, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Dear Scotch...Thank You. It worked. Is there a way in which I can format the contents of the Excel to make it look better. And I want an Excel to be created opened up without a name. I want to leave it to the user to choose where and name it. How can I do it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to have it automatically format nicely in Excel, I've had that same problem. There is a way to use an existing formatted Excel sheet, but I'm not too sure. if you want the user to be able to name it from access, create a text box control "txtExportName", and in your vb code, I think you could do docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "qryExport", "C:\yourPath\" & [Forms]![yourForm]![txtExportName] & ".xlsm", True

Answer (score 1):

OK, simple enough. You'll have to use VBA.

On the click event of the button, you'll just have to execute a DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet command. There's several options so you can just look it up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

For the *table name*, use a query instead that includes a reference to your ComboBox. I.e. `=[Forms]![FormName]![ControlName]`